# I lose Data when i scroll my ListView in Android

Tags: android, listview

I am using ListView to show TextViews in some rows and not others. I don't know how many items there will be, it runs fine but when I scroll down the display changed. 

**For example:**
If I have 10 items in ListView, and only 5 of them are currently visible. Adapter returns positions from 0 to 4 correctly...thats ok. When I scroll down position of item 10 and return to the top, I get all my items looking like the first item on the list, and if I scroll many times I get the first item repeated 10 times.

Im using ArrayAdapter.
**Here's some code:**

```
@Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View row = convertView;
        PlanningHolder holder = null;
        if (row == null) {
            row = mInflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);

            holder = new PlanningHolder();
            holder.numberOfJour = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.numberDate);
            holder.lay = (LinearLayout) row.findViewById(R.id.layPlage);

            row.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (PlanningHolder) row.getTag();
        }

        if(position%2 == 1){
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                    LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);

            params.setMargins(50, 5, 30, 5);
            //MarginLayoutParams marginLayoutParams = (MarginLayoutParams) params.getLayoutParams();

            //marginLayoutParams.setMargins(marginleft, 5, display.getWidth() - marginright, 5);
            TextView newplage = new TextView(context);
            newplage.setLayoutParams(params);
            newplage.setBackgroundColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.darkorrange));

            holder.lay.addView(newplage);
        }

        holder.numberOfJour.setText(myPlannig.getCurrent().get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) + "");

        row.setId(position);
        return row;
    }
```

and this is my listView declaration:

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/list_planning"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:background="@drawable/top_shadow"
    android:scrollingCache="true"
    android:dividerHeight="1dp">
</ListView>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is caused by reusing `convertView`. Either disable faulty optimization

```
View row = null;
```

or repair optimization by implementing `else` branch of `if` and set `row` views `numberDate`, `layPlage` appropriately for this case.

Notice that you are adding views to `holder.lay` but you never remove them. They accumulate when you are scrolling and reusing `convertView`.

Comment: thanks for the answers but in the else case i wont my `holder.lay` without any views.

Comment: So delete them from `holder.lay` in `else` block.

Answer (score 2):

This is a common case in list view. You must handle if and else case correctly.

For example, if you set text in if case and not in else case, then the old value gets retained. The views in list view are getting recycled.

When you first open the list view, it is getting created.

When you scroll back and forth, You are loading data over an already existing view which already had values.

Whatever you handle in the if case within the `getView`, you must probably **undo** it in the else. In other words, you must handle the views in every case or path the code flows in the `getView` method.

Answer (score 0):

Put else condition like this

```
else
{
lay.addView(newplage);
}
```